# Center li elements inside ul list

Tags: html, css

I have an issue with centering `li` elements inside of a `ul`.

Here is the JSFiddle I made: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e87yhgwy/)
And this is my CSS (same as in the JSFiddle):

```
.all-collections{
  text-align:center;
}
.all-collections ul{
  list-style:none;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:40%;
}
.all-collections ul li{
  float:left;
  margin-left:10px;
}
```

I need to center the floated elements, the last three items should be centered. 
Can you please suggest a way I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
.all-collections{
  text-align:center;
}
.all-collections ul{
  list-style:none;
  margin:0 auto;
  width:40%;
  text-align: center;
}
.all-collections ul li{
  display: inline-block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e87yhgwy/1/

Comment: thanks a lot! it works